# FileUploaderPlugin - MultiPartDataMediaFormatterBoundary error on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting an error when trying to upload files to android using the [FileUploaderPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin), even one file doesn't work.

When using the Upload method I am using the option which takes an array of FileBytesItem to pass through multiple byte arrays.This works nicely on iOS but fails on Android.  I am assuming this is a header issue with OkHttp

I get the information below in the Error handler

MultiPartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name ="[0].Key"

MultiPartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name ="[0].Value"

An error has occurred

Content-Type : "multipart/form-data"

StatusCode: 500

I have tried adding options like a boundary string with the '-' characters and a unique id and also by specifying the Content-Type & Content-Disposition directly but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `500` means the error happens on the server side, please check/debug your server side app to find the error.

Comment: The same server code works fine for iOS & the files are uploaded, doesn't this mean its got something to do with a header or the way its being sent

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was passing a dynamic value to the field name in FileBytesItem and it seems to fail on Android with a 500 error if it has slash character(s) in it. This doesn't seems to cause an issue on iOS